# How to load a file that has been created on the same run in Java

Tags: java, javafx, runtime

I'm creating an application that uses graphviz to generate a png image, after it has been created I want to load the image on a ImageView, not sure what is the best approach here, this is my latest try:

```
private void generateGraph() throws IOException {
    Graph g = graph("example15").directed().with(node("a").link(node("b"));
    Graphviz.fromGraph(g).width(200).render(Format.PNG).toFile(new File("src/main/resources/graphs/ex15.png"));
}

public void handleImageLoad(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
        // Image here is a JavaFX image, thats why I can load an image from
        // the resources folder directly
        Image image = new Image("graphs/ex15.png");
        loadGraphPNG(image);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }        
}
```

The method `handleImageLoad` is called by a button press, however even after the file is created (I confirm that by looking at the folder) the program prints out the message "File not found!" thrown by the catch clausule. On the other hand if I try to load a file that was already in the resources folder, it loads just fine. So the question is, how can I create a Image and load it into a ImageView, if the file was created at runtime? Thank you.

Comment: Be consistent... The two paths are not the same. Beware not to create anything in `src` dir, when your app will be deployed it is highly unprobable that this dir will exist.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to try to access the source folder hierarchy (`src/...`) at runtime; typically (basically any time except during development) the source code is not available at runtime. If you need to store a file, you probably need to do so either in the system temp folder (see, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) or in the user home directory. I don't know graphviz, but can't it just give you an input stream to read the image?

Comment: The way you load the image JavaFX is looking for it in the classpath. Writing the file to the source directory does not automatically include it in the build path before the next rebuild. In general only resources that are nor modified should be added as resources...